# Doing Prediction of currency with HMM

Tags: r, prediction, hidden-markov-models

I have made that codes and I just stuck in this part with this error

```
# Memasukkan data baru ke dalam model HMM kurs jual
HMM_fm_kurs_jual_pred <- update(HMM_fm_kurs_jual, data = new_data_ts_jual)
**Error in methods::slot(object, name) : 
  no slot of name "call" for this object of class "depmix.fitted"**
```

I have tried to fix them like checking the codes and find some references but it's just the same